# Least-square fitting for points in 2d doesn't pass through symmetrical axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, numpy, linear-regression

I'm trying to draw the best fitting line for given (x,y) data points.

[image]

Here shows data points (red pixels) and estimated line (green), I obtained using following library.

```
import numpy as np    
m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y)[0]
```

Documentation for used [library module](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html)

We can see data points are roughly symmetrically distributed. Problem is why is this line not having the gradient similar to the long symmetric axis through the data points? Can you please explain can this result is correct? Then, how it gives minimum error? (Line is drawn correctly using gradient returned by the `lstsq` method). Thank you.

**EDIT**

Here is the code I'm trying. Input image can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByyTOMaRbWRcRDMyZHhOLVRrMUE). In this code I've not forced the line to pass through the center of the pixel distribution. (Note: here I've used `polyfit` instead of `lstsq`. Both gives same results)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math

img = cv2.imread('points.jpg',1);
h, w = img.shape[:2]
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

points = np.argwhere(gray>10)    # get (x,y) pairs where red pixels exist
y = points[:,0]
x = points[:,1]

m, c = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)      # calculate least square fit line

# calculate two cordinates (x1,y1),(x2,y2) on the line
angle = np.arctan(m)
x1, y1, length =  0, int(c), 500
x2 =  int(round(math.ceil(x1 + length * np.cos(angle)),0))
y2 =  int(round(math.ceil(y1 + length * np.sin(angle)),0))
# draw line on the color image
cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0,255,0), 1, cv2.LINE_8)
# show output the image
cv2.namedWindow("Display window", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cv2.imshow("Display window", img);
cv2.waitKey(0);
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How can I have the line pass through the longest symmetric axis of the pixel distribution? Can I use principle component analysis?

Comment: I agree that the green line doesn't look right

Comment: However, this is not reproducible without data

Comment: This is not a density plot. If the long hands of the plot are spread thin, while the core is dense and skewed, you could expect this kind of fit. Also least square regression is not a robust method. I would second the request for the data that Jared posted above.

Comment: Regression line is not going to be the line of symmetry (reason [explained here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/brain-and-cognitive-sciences/9-07-statistical-methods-in-brain-and-cognitive-science-spring-2004/lecture-notes/15_corr_regres2.pdf), page 7). If you treat x as a function of y (which appears to be the case), the resulting line is not unexpected.

Comment: I have added an issue reproducible code. thank you.

Comment: Were you able to sort this out in the end?

Comment: @vestland What I needed was angle of the symmetric axis of the distribution. Center of the distribution was fixed. Therefore I took polar coordinates of all the points relative to the center of the distribution, then got the maximum occurring angle. But you have given the best answer for here in this question. So I'll mark your one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the red dots truly represent your data, you are probably applying your linear regression function in a way that forces the line through the origin. How do i know? When using linear regression on two variables x and y, the line will intercept a few specific points. For example the average of x, and the average of y. Also, depending on your specifications, a calculated or specified intercept of the y axis. If all variables of x and y are positive, you will have a line that looks like yours if the line is forced through the origin. Not much more can be said before you provide som reproducible data and code.

**EDIT:**
I didn't have much luck with the reproducble sample provided, so I built an example with random numbers to elaborate on my original answer. I think statsmodels is a decent library for linear regression analysis. First, I'll address this earlier comment:

> If all variables of x and y are positive, you will have a line that looks like yours if the line is forced through the origin.

You'll see an increasing effect of this the larger your numbers are (the further away from the origin your numbers are). Using `sm.OLS(y,sm.add_constant(x)).fit()` and `sm.OLS(y,x).fit()` for two different sets of numbers will show you exactly what I mean. First, I'll run a regression on the dataset below **without** an estimated constant (the line goes through the origin). This will give us a plot that at resembles your original plot:

```
# Libraries
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data
np.random.seed(123)
x = np.random.normal(size=2500) + 100
y = x * 2 + np.random.normal(size=2500) + 100

# Regression
results1 = sm.OLS(y,x).fit()
regLine_origin  = x*results1.params[0]

# PLot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y, c='red', s=4)
ax.scatter(x, regLine_origin, c = 'green', s = 1)

ax.patch.set_facecolor('black')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Next, I'll include a constant in the regression. Now, the yellow line will represent what I think you were after in your question:

```
# Libraries
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data
np.random.seed(123)
x = np.random.normal(size=2500) + 100
y = x * 2 + np.random.normal(size=2500) + 100

# Regression
results1 = sm.OLS(y,x).fit()
results2 = sm.OLS(y,sm.add_constant(x)).fit()
regLine_origin  = x*results1.params[0]
regLine_constant =  results2.params[0] + x*results2.params[1]

# PLot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y, c='red', s=4)
ax.scatter(x, regLine_origin, c = 'green', s = 1)
ax.scatter(x, regLine_constant, c = 'yellow', s = 1)

ax.patch.set_facecolor('black')
plt.show()
```

[image]

And lastly, we can take a look at what happens when the numbers are closer to the origin. So to speak. Here, I'll remove the +100 part when the numbers are produced:

```
# The following is changed in the snippet above:
# Data
x = np.random.normal(size=2500)
y = x * 2 + np.random.normal(size=2500)
```

[image]

And that's why I think your original regression line is set to go through the origin. Have a look at the statsmodels package. Here you can study the details of the estimate by running `print(results2.summary())`:

[image]

And as you've already seen in the snippets above, you'll have direct access to the regression coefficients by using `results2.params`.

[image]

**Edit2:** My explanation still isn't 100% valid. The x and y values will have to differ a bit in size to see this effect. You'll certainly find situations where the line goes through the origin no matter the size of the numbers.
Have a look at the different x labels, and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say why this would be the case.  The bottom line is that I can't see the data you're using, and I can't see what the calculated slope and y intercept are for the data you're using.

Here are a couple of things that could explain what we're seeing:
(1) The density of data points is actually quite different than it appears to a casual glance and everything is working properly.
(2) You're sending the wrong arguments to the least squares function and you've got a GIGO situation.  (I haven't used numpy's least squares algorithm, so I can't check this.)
(3) The scatter plot and the line plot don't agree on the scale of the axes.
(4) The least squares function in question is broken.
(5) You're not passing the same data to the least squares algorithm as you're passing to the plotting routine.
(6) The data formatting is funky so that the scatter plot and least squares routines are interpreting your data differently.

I can't know which of these is the problem, and unless it's (3), I expect we'd need more data to be able to distinguish between these possibilities.

Here's how I'd proceed if I were you: (1) Create a small artificial data set that sits on a line and pass it to the least squares function and see if it spits out the right numbers.  See if these look right when plotted or not.  (2) If this looks okay, record the output of the least squares algorithm, see if you can find another least squares program to calculate the slope and y intercept and compare them.  If they're the same, it's probably not the routine, it's probably something to do with plotting.

If you get this far and it's still a mystery, let us know what you've found and maybe we can make another suggestion.

Good luck.

Comment: I applied the same algorithm for known dataset. as well as other unknown datasets aggreed to my hypothesis. those lines pass through the symmetric axis. this is the only case i got unexpected results. I will update the question to an issue reproducable way, give me 2h. thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your first sentence at all, what is this hypothesis?  What do you think is wrong?  I'm less interested in your code than your data.  Is it possible you can post that somewhere along with what your line's slope and y intercept are?

Comment: hypothesis is " regression line should have the gradient similar to the longest symmetrical axis through the data points"